# RVM and Ruby not available to new user

Tags: ruby, bash, rvm

I have installed RVM for a user (which installed Ruby 2), I then also installed JRuby using RVM for the same user.  This first user is the user I usually work in (developing).

My application runs under its own user.  I created the application user, but find that rvm, ruby, jruby and gems that are available to the first user are not available to the second (ex: rvm:command not found).

I believe this has something to do with PATH and env variables, but haven't been able to find my solution in searches.

Any help is appreciated.  Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

rvm is installed in the executing user's home directory by default. Also, by default, other users don't have access to said home directory. The solution would be to install rvm under the new users' home directory and to initialise it in their .profile.

There is a [multi-user](https://rvm.io/rvm/install/) option, where you install it and add users to the `rvm` group, but that's not the recommended way to install [rvm](http://rvm.io). However, it does seem to be what you need to do.

Comment: So that user would need to have sudo privileges? (when running `\curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --rails --autolibs=enabled` it asks for sudo password) - I dont' need to re-install my rubies and gems for each user do I?